# How to configure AutoMapper to not check the member list while mapping?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm creating maps like below while passing member list option to `None`:

```
CreateMap<Level, LevelVM>(MemberList.None);
```

But I don't want to do it for every map I create. I'd like to have this setting applied globally, as default. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can do it using ForAllMaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, AutoMapper tries to map all properties of the source type to the destination type. If some of the properties are not available in the destination type it will not throw an exception when doing the mapping. However, it will throw an exception when you are using ValidateMapperConfiguration().

```
  class SourceType
    {
        public string Value1 { get; set; }
    }


class DestinationType
{    
    public string Value1{ get; set; }
    public string Value2{ get; set; }
}
```

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException : The following 1
>   properties on DestinationType are not mapped:     Value2 Add a custom
>   mapping expression, ignore, or rename the property on SourceType.

You can override this behavior by making Global setting to ignore all properties that do not exist on the target type.
You can do setting over class level or property level or global like as I said

Simply add below code in Global.asax

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
       cfg.ValidateInlineMaps = false
    }
```

At property, level ignores the Value2 property while doing the mapping between these two objects. To do so we need to use the AutoMapper Ignore Property with the Address property of

```
config.CreateMap<SourceType,DestinationType>()
                    //Ignoring the Value2  property of the destination type
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Value2 , act => act.Ignore());
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly it does? The [documentation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Inline-Mapping.html) says that "(...) turns off inline map validation (not recommended unless you’re explicitly testing all of your maps)." but to be honest, I do not understand the consequences.

Comment: I updated my answer please check. I hope It will help you

Comment: Will global setting cfg.ValidateInlineMaps = false effectively defeat the purpose of configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); call ?